# QoS & SMB protocol: slow directory listing while uploading

Tags: windows, router, smb, qos, webdav

I have mounted an online cloud storage service via SMB as virtual drive on my Windows 10. I am on a 100/10 internet connection and the performance of the SMB drive is in general quite good.

However, directory listings in File Explorer are becoming very slow each time I am copying data to the virtual drive (uploading). It seems that my router's automatic QoS management is unable to set aside enough bandwidth for the listing request to come through quickly. Other services, such as VoIP, are not negatively impacted.

I have noticed that all SMB activity goes through the same TCP connection on my computer. No matter how many activities I perform on the SMB drive in parallel, there is always only a single TCP connection to the server on port 445. Maybe this explains why my router's automatic QoS management is failing. I have also noticed that this problem does not occur when mounting the drive using WebDav which uses several TCP connections in parallel.

The cloud storage service is called Hetzner Storage Box. My router is ASUS DSL-N66U. My QoS bandwidth settings on the router are set to 90/9 to reflect real world speed testing results.

What can I do to speed up directory listing over SMB?

Comment: This is likely a bufferbloat bug (breaking TCP congestion control and increasing latency). Enable Smart Queueing (CoDel or PIE, plus ECN) on your router. You may need to load open source firmware (OpenWrt, etc) to do this.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, @Spiff. My router doesn't seem to support any open source firmware. Are there any settings in Windows that could lead to an improvement?